# Find a float in a lua string

Tags: string, lua

Not much else to say.

I need to find full numbers, not just integers;

```
print(("3"):match("%d+"))
```

-> 3

```
print(("3.14"):match("%d+"))
```

-> still 3, I need to match "3.14"

Comment: every compiler book has this as a question for students and many valid solutions exist [online](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk01r5i2U78wJdp2aQm060FgRDg9Eig%3A1615664993074&ei=YRdNYOWIBJyKjLsPlKmcyAs&q=regex+float&oq=regex+float&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBwgjELADECcyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsAMyBwgAEEcQsANQoDJYoDJg-TNoAXABeACAAbABiAGoApIBAzAuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQnAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwilvfOPha7vAhUcBWMBHZQUB7kQ4dUDCA0&uact=5).

Comment: Try this pattern`"%d+%.?%d*"`

Comment: How about `".5"` and `"3."`? (both "difficult" to represent exactly in (normalised) binary floating point)

Answer (score 1):

```lua
print(("3.14"):match("%d+%.?%d*"))
```